# Executable stops working after code signing

Tags: java, windows, code-signing, launch4j, signtool

I have built an executable for a Java application using Launch4J. I am embedding JRE and Uber Jar in the executable. The executable works.

However, after I perform code signing on the executable using signtool, it stops working. Here is the command that I use to sign the executable:

`signtool sign /td sha1 /fd sha1 /f my_certificate.pfx /p mypass myexecutable.exe`

Here is the error that shows up in a dialog box:

```
Java Virtual Machine Launcher
Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile
```

Why my executable stops working after code signing?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue when signing files generated by launch4j. The workaround is to specify the main class in the launch4j configuration instead of relying on an executable jar with a Main-Class attribute in its manifest:

```
<classPath>
  <mainClass>org.acme.Main</mainClass>
</classPath>
```

See https://github.com/ebourg/jsign/issues/80 for more information.